# Is getting Schufa entries you don't recognize deleted always advantageous?

Tags: credit-score, germany

I recently obtained my credit score information from Schufa. I chose the free option ("Datenkopie"). The oldest entry is this one (blanked out by me):

[image]

I don't remember ever having done business with that company. That's not to say I didn't, I just don't remember. But I'm sure I don't have an active contract with them. So I should be able to get that one deleted.

But is there actually any advantage to getting it deleted? I have very few entries (in chronological order: that one, two by two different banks (1 each), one because of my credit card contract, and one because I once asked for a different credit card (but that one got declined)). So given that there will only be 4 entries left and one of them definitely is negative, should I leave that one in there?

Comment: Is it your phone number, or someone else's, in the space you blacked out?

Comment: It's a customer number, not a phone number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entry says that you have an active phone contract. It does not say that you didn't pay your phone bills on time, so the assumption is you always did that. This is not a bad entry. So getting that entry deleted would likely not improve your credit score. It could in fact make it worse because you now have less history of being a reliable debtor. The only way how it could contribute to a bad score is if you have so many ongoing fixcosts that it already overburdens you financially and makes it unlikely that you can fulfill another contract demanding a monthly payment.

If you are not sure how that contract came to be, keep in mind that [Mobilcom-Debitel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobilcom-Debitel) is a corporation with multiple subsideries and brands. Your business relation might be under one of those. Do *Klarmobil* or *Callmobile* ring a bell? It is also part of [the Freenet group](https://www.freenet-group.de/markenwelt/index.html), an even larger conglomerat. It is possible that you made a contract with one of the other companies which belong to Freenet and that contract was later transferred to Mobilcom-Debitel as part of some internal restructuring.

Comment: Yes, Klarmobil does ring a bell. Thank you for the hint that there are different brands that that corporation owns.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the rating algorithm of Schufa is their trade secret. (One of the critiques of that system) so nobody can really answer this question for sure.

What hearsay I have in my head is:

- it´s bad to have many scoring pulls with no followup transaction. (you didn´t get the loan etc.) edit thanks to comments: [SCHUFA says this is not the case](https://www.schufa.de/de/faq/privatpersonen/scoring/#collapse_165764_11)
- Its bad to have too many small loans, cellphone contracts etc.
- It´s good to have some history of paying off something.
- Obviously its bad if you can´t pay you loan/Cell phone etc..

Comment: [According to SCHUFA themselves](https://www.schufa.de/de/faq/privatpersonen/scoring/), the first bullet point is a myth. They say that pulling your score (either through a DSGVO request or through a regular score pull) does not affect your score.

Comment: According to my Sister, who worked in Banking if you ask for a loan on the house at three different banks and the all pull schufa, your rating goes down so only the first bank will make you a good offer.

Comment: @Daniel: I'm inclined to believe Philipp and the Schufa on this. I've heard bankers say that and in fact the first offer was the best one for us, but I'm pretty sure that's because the first banker listened to us (the other two made plans outside our parameters, even though one of them had even lower total interest than the first offer) and not because of anything Schufa. I think bankers tell that myth in order to discourage you from shopping around too much for a loan with good rates - gives them higher odds of making the best offer and getting you as a customer.